# I believe Usage

Tags: word-usage

How strong is the word "I believe"?
Since we have different constructions on how we define such statement, I'll give this as an example,

If someone says: "I believe killing anybody is a sin" 
Would that be a proposition that he/she's still doubtful about killing as a sin? or is it a strong reaction on what he/ she believes in?

Comment: In writing, the "I believe" in your sentence would be taken as a statement of opinion or deeply held belief. In speaking, though, "I believe" is spoken quite emphatically when used in this sense, while it's spoken with more of a questioning voice when expressing an assumption—as in "I believe he's at home (*but I'm not certain of it*)."

Comment: @ralph.m has described the essence of the ambiguity- the sentence, as written, could mean either depending on how it's spoken.  Please provide more context.

Answer (score 2):

It's a fairly strong and absolute statement -- he's definitely opposed to murder.

But of course humans can always "weasel word" things:  The speaker might still favor capital punishment and/or accept the necessity to kill others in a war.

There are other contexts, though, where "believe" just means "feel" or "suspect".  Eg, "I believe the engine has a bad spark plug" -- the speaker is not married to the idea but is offering it as a supposition.

Answer (score 1):

While "believe" is not the strongest word to suggest one's views and principles, it doesn't imply doubt. It is still preferable to "think" and "feel" which tend to indicate a more fickle outlook. For clarification, use "strongly believe" if you want to indicate a stronger conviction.